# Ajuste de Layout Material Design

Tags: css, slider, material-design, materialize

Eu não consigo fazer com que o Slide tome toda a area da tela home , note que metade da Section **"estrutura"** é visto na home do site, já tentei de tudo, mas eu não sou bom com CSS, infelizmente.

```
<div id="intro" class="section scrollspy">

      <div class="slider">
        <ul class="slides">
          <li>
            <img src="imagem"> <!-- random image -->
            <div class="caption center-align">
              <h3>Lazer a seu alcance.</h3>
              <h5 class="light grey-text text-lighten-3">Espaço pensado e estruturado para o seu lazer.</h5>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Exemplo funcional [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vfwd6uuz/)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite sua pergunta e forneça mais detalhes se não vai acabar recebendo votos negativos, pois sua pergunta não está clara.

Comment: Você quer que o slide ocupe toda a tela, mas que ao rolar a página apareça as outras divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia!

Você pode simplesmente colocar uma altura, assim como:
height: 100vh;
Ou seja, ele pega 100 partes da tua tela para a div que você aplicar
Lembrando que se quiser que o slider e o menu pegue a mesma altura junto, você pode colocar por exemplo para o menu:
.menu{
   height: 10vh;
}
.slider{
   height: 90vh;
}

Ou talvez até deixar o menu como position: absolute; e o slide com 100vh ficando atras do menu.

Comment: Show, era isso que eu precisava, muito obrigado.